# Android SafetyNet quota over 10.000

Tags: safetynet, safetynet-api

We have many applications in the store that authorize through SafetyNet. In total, there can be more than 100,000 users per day. To get a quota of more than 10 thousand, I need to fill out an application from Google. But in one of the fields I need to fill  packageName. It turns out that the increased quota will be only for the listed applications? The problem is that there are more than a thousand applications in total and new ones appear every day.

Answer (score 0):

You just fill the form for your applications that you want their quota to be increased, can't understand your question here.